# Linux/Unix VBScript Compatibility

Tags: linux, windows, unix, vbscript, migration

I am a Windows Developer and recently got a fresh install of Windows 7.
I experienced an issue because of 30-Day trial things, and went to Linux
as my go-to desktop experience.

When I named a file with a "`.vbs`" extension on Windows, it knew it was a Visual Basic script. However on Linux it just said "text document" and ignored it.

Is there any compatibility without emulating Windows or using Wine for VBS?
If not, is there any alternative for Unix/Linux?

Comment: Linux has plenty of scripting languages available, but not ones written by Microsoft...  So no, you can't write VBS or Powershell for Linux - they won't run.  You might be better looking at the likes of `python`?

Comment: JFTR, you're aware that you can extend the trial period by running `slmgr /rearm` up to 3 times?

Comment: @Dave & fans: There is https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell and http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: I know of Mono, but it's broken on the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for answering.